# bi-invertible maps is a mere proposition (HoTT)

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

Equivalences in HoTT can be defined using bi-invertible maps. For a function
$f : A\to B$ this is defined to be
$$
\mathsf{biinv}(f) :\equiv \left(\Sigma_{h : B\to A}(h\circ f \sim id_A)\right)\times\left(\Sigma_{g : B\to A}(f\circ g\sim id_B\right)
$$

This is for every $f$ a mere proposition. But I'm not sure how to prove this. There is a proof in the HoTT-Book but it is burried under a lot of theorems. I was wondering if there is a more direct way to see what happens here. Especially since this type is a mere proposition and
$$
\mathsf{qinv}(f) :\equiv \Sigma_{g : B\to A}\left((g\circ f \sim id_A)\times(f\circ g\sim id_B)\right)
$$
is not.

#### Own Ideas

So, to start, the product type preserves propositions, so it is sufficient to look at the components of $\times$, and they look fairly symmetric, which probably yields two analogous proof.
Therefore, let's consider why 
$$
\Sigma_{h : B\to A}(h\circ f \sim id_A)
$$
is a mere proposition.

Now, what needs to be shown is that for any $u,v : 
\Sigma_{h : B\to A}(h\circ f \sim id_A)$ we have $u = v$. By the higher order structure of dependent pairs, this is equivalent to
$$
  \Sigma_{p : \mathsf{pr}_1(u)=\mathsf{pr}_2(v)}\mathsf{transport}^{h\mapsto (h\circ f \sim id_A)}(p, \mathsf{pr}_2(u)) = \mathsf{pr}_2(v)
$$
By function extensionality, $h\circ f \sim id_A$ is equivalent to $h \circ f = id_A$, and since $\mathsf{biinv}(f)\to\mathsf{qinv}(f)$, there is a quasi-inverse $f^{-1}$. Hence
$$
   h \circ f \circ f^{-1} = id_A \circ f^{-1}
$$
and therefore $h = f^{-1}$, for any such $h$. So, there exists such a path $p$, but it is not clear to me, how to transport along this path...